# How to retrieve an image from ImageView when Click on that image?

Tags: android, onclick, imageview

i have a ImageView in the layout, when i click on the image i want to get that image into a variable and replace with another image in this ImageView. please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onClick` Listener will give you a `View`, that's the `ImageView` that was clicked. Cast it to an `ImageView` and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: how to get image from the view

Comment: Just as you do with every other `ImageView`, call its `getDrawable()`.

Comment: You decided to skip the part of my comment where I mention you should cast it to an `ImageView`...

Comment: Do a google search on casting then, which is a generic programming concept and not some Android related feature.

Answer (score 2):

in this example i have take previous image in Drawable and replace `i` with new image. if you set any imageview to image which stay in drawable variable(d) then use ::   `setBackgroundDrawable(d);` is useful

```
 public void onClick(View v){
   ImageView i;
        i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        Drawable d = i.getBackground();
        i.setBackgroundResource(R.id.secondImage);

   }
```